# Parse string with currency symbol and value

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter, currency-formatting

I am trying to parse a list of input strings from an Excel file that can have a 'currency' value, and it could be in any currency. For e.g.

- $200
- £300
- €200
- CA$300

What's the best way to parse out the currency symbol and the numeric value? I'm trying to do this with a `NumberFormatter` but it doesn't work for the 'euro' or the 'CAD' value.

Here is my code:

```
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

let trimmedString = String(currencyString.filter { String($0).rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.,")) == nil }).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

if trimmedString.count > 0 && Locale.current.currencySymbol != trimmedString {
    // Currency symbol is *not* local currency, so lookup the locale for it
    let allLocales = Locale.availableIdentifiers.map({Locale(identifier: $0)})
    if let localeForSymbol = allLocales.filter({$0.currencySymbol == trimmedString}).first {
        currencyFormatter.locale = localeForSymbol
    }
}

if let numberValue = currencyFormatter.number(from: currencyString) {
    print ("\(NSDecimalNumber(decimal: numberValue.decimalValue))")
}
```

What am I getting wrong here? Or is this not possible without using some regex expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this "...to parse out the currency symbol and the numeric value":

```
let currencyString = "CA$300"

let valueString = currencyString.filter {
    CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.,").isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: String($0)))
}.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
print("---> valueString: \(valueString) ")

let symbol = currencyString.replacingOccurrences(of: valueString, with: "")
print("---> symbol: \(symbol)")
```

Answer (score 0):

@workingdog has a valid answer.  An alternative, and one I always reach for, is to use regex, where 3 simple regex can be used to identify any non-numeric leading characters, the numeric characters, and any non-numeric postfix characters:

```
let prefixRegex = #"^[^0-9]+"#
let numRegex = #"[0-9]+"#
let postfixRegex = #"[^0-9]+$"#
```

These can then be used with String's `.range(of: options:)` using the `.regularExpression` option to get the element's range, and then use that to extract the relevant SubString.

As a very quick demo of this in action:

```
["$20", "£300", "€200", "CA$300", "798xyz", "$123abc"]
   .forEach{string in
      var components: [Range<String.Index>?] = []
      
      components.append( string.range(of: prefixRegex, options: .regularExpression))
      components.append( string.range(of: numRegex, options: .regularExpression))
      components.append( string.range(of: postfixRegex, options: .regularExpression))
      
      print(components
         .map{ $0 != nil ? String(string[$0!]).padded(to: 8) : String(repeating: " ", count: 8) }
         .joined(separator: "")
      )
   }
```

This provides an output of

```
$       20              
£       300             
€       200             
CA$     300             
        798     xyz     
$       123     abc
```

`.padded(to:)` is a utility extension on String that pads the rear of a string to a specified length with any character.

```
extension String {
   func padded(to paddedTo :Int, with padding: String = " ") -> Self {
      while count < paddedTo {
         return (self + padding).padded(to: paddedTo, with: padding)
      }
      return self
   }
}
```

Comment: you should provide an implementation of `String.padded(to:)`

Comment: Also, wouldn't the map statement be cleaner as `.map{ String(string[$0 ?? "".startIndex ..< "".startIndex]).padded(to:8)`?

Comment: @DuncanC  Ithe `padded(to:)` wasn't relevant to the main answer to the question, but you are right I should add one so the demo is working.  I'm not sure your map is better as it's harder to parse visually, and for someone new to Swift therefore probably more obscure.  But both are there now so they have a choice :-)